# Combine multiple line which having same start pattern

Tags: shell, awk

I have text file which having following content..

```
-country
-the
-elections
+countries
+be
+a
+chance
-the
-means
-we
+need
+people’s
+choice
-democracy
+democracies
-elections
-there
+increases
+their
```

I want merge line which is having same starting pattern. For above file output should be

```
-country -the -elections 
+countries +be +a +chance
-the -means -we
+need +people’s +choice
-democracy
+democracies
-elections -there
+increases +their
```

I have tried with

```
sed '/^-/{N;s/\n/ /}' diff_1.txt
```

but its merging line which start with - and that is also wrong not as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```
awk '{ch=substr($0,1,1)} p != ch{if (NR>1) print s; s=""}
{p=ch; s = (s != "" ? s " " $0 : $0)} END{print s}' file
```

```
-country -the -elections
+countries +be +a +chance
-the -means -we
+need +people’s +choice
-democracy
+democracies
-elections -there
+increases +their
```

Comment: But its missing last part of file i.e. +increases
+their

Answer (score 1):

Using Perl

```
> cat amol.txt
-country
-the
-elections
+countries
+be
+a
+chance
-the
-means
-we
+need
+people’s
+choice
-democracy
+democracies
-elections
-there
+increases
+their
> perl -lne ' $c=substr($_,0,1) ;$tp=$tc;$tc.="$_"." "; if($.>1 and $p ne $c) { print "$tp";$tc=$_." ";} $p=$c; END { print "$tc" } ' amol.txt
-country -the -elections
+countries +be +a +chance
-the -means -we
+need +people’s +choice
-democracy
+democracies
-elections -there
+increases +their
>
```

or even shorter

```
> perl -lne ' $c=substr($_,0,1) ;$tp=$tc;$tc.="$_"." "; print "$tp" and $tc=$_." " if $.>1 and $p ne $c ; $p=$c; END { print "$tc" } ' amol.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another awk:

```
awk '{c=substr($0,1,1); printf (c==t ? OFS : ORS) $0; t=c}'
```

This will, however, introduce an empty line before everything.

You can get rid of that in the following way:

```
awk '{c=substr($0,1,1); printf (c==t ? OFS : (NR==1?"":ORS)) $0; t=c}'
```